# MySql counting the number of groups of rows containing a certain value

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I get the number of "groups" of a status, where status == 0, excluding groups which start the table and groups that span <= hour? (If the time constraint is too difficult, we can alternatively exclude groups with counts <= 40 instead of groups spanning <= hour, since a row is logged about every 1:30 minutes.)

For example, the following SAMPLE table WITHOUT the time constraint would produce 3 if grouping by status == 0.

```
+------+----------+----------+
| id   | status   |time      |
+------+----------+----------+
| 0001 | 1        |11:32:48  |
+------+----------+----------+
| 0002 | 0        |11:30:26  |
+------+----------+----------+
| 0003 | 0        |11:28:54  |
+------+----------+----------+
| 0004 | 1        |11:27:23  |
+------+----------+----------+
| 0005 | 0        |11:25:52  |
+------+----------+----------+
| 0006 | 1        |11:24:20  |
+------+----------+----------+
| 0007 | 1        |11:22:48  |
+------+----------+----------+
| 0008 | 0        |11:21:17  |
+------+----------+----------+
| 0009 | 0        |11:19:45  |
+------+----------+----------+
| 0010 | 0        |11:18:14  |
+------+----------+----------+
| 0011 | 0        |11:16:43  |
+------+----------+----------+
| 0012 | 0        |11:15:11  |
+------+----------+----------+
| 0013 | 0        |11:13:39  |
+------+----------+----------+
| 0002 | 0        |11:12:08  |
+------+----------+----------+
| 0014 | 1        |11:10:37  |
+------+----------+----------+
| 0015 | 1        |11:09:05  |
+------+----------+----------+
| 0016 | 1        |11:07:33  |
+------+----------+----------+
| 0017 | 0        |11:06:02  |
+------+----------+----------+
```

One solution I can think of would be to grab the entire table and produce the result with Java, but I am afraid this would be too inefficient given that the table can have millions of entries.

Comment: are you trying to get the # of groups for a specific status or all statuses?

Comment: Why should be 3, it shouldn't be 4 when status == 0?

Comment: @FuzzyTree for a specific status, namely when status ==0

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza 3 because the first group does not count since it is at the start of the table

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. What would be the result for 1 in this case, 3 or 2? I consider that 2 is a possible result because a group may contain at least 2 elements, but if not then it should be 3.

Comment: @Simon If you do not want to count the first continuous streak, perhaps you can do a -1 from the count of streaks?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza for 1, i got 4

(0014, 0015, 0016)---(0006,0007)---(0004)---(0001)

we count the first occurrence of 1 because it did not START the table.

Comment: In your current example, the table starts with status 1, not with 0. Now I'm more confused.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza sorry for the confusion luiggi. I count id 17 as the start of my table because it is the earliest entry.

Comment: So you first have to sort the data from time, then start counting all groups based on stat (until <= time) and you should decrease the counter by 1 in case the state of the group is the same as the state of the group that *starts* in the table, right?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes, if by (until<=time) you mean to only count groups which have entries where the difference of the first and last entry of the GROUP is greater than an hour.

Comment: @Simon There are 2 rows with id = `0002` in your sample data above!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select sum(is_different_from_previous) , status
from (
    select status, 
    (@prevStatus <> status and @prevStatus <> -1) is_different_from_previous,
    @prevStatus := status
    from myTable t1
    cross join (select @prevStatus := -1) t2
    order by t1.time
) t1 group by status
```

for a specific status

```
select * from (
    select sum(is_different_from_previous) , status
    from (
        select status, 
        (@prevStatus <> status and @prevStatus <> -1) is_different_from_previous,
        @prevStatus := status
        from myTable t1
        cross join (select @prevStatus := -1) t2
        order by t1.time
    ) t1 group by status
) t1 where status = 0
```

**Edit**

To only count groups with a certain # of 0s

```
select count(*) from (
    select * from (
        select status, 
        (@prevStatus <> status and @prevStatus <> -1) is_different_from_previous,
        if(@prevStatus <> status and @prevStatus <> -1,@groupNumber := @groupNumber + 1, @groupNumber) groupNumber,
        @prevStatus := status
        from myTable t1
        cross join (select @prevStatus := -1, @groupNumber := 0) t2
        order by t1.id
    ) t1
    where status = 0
    group by groupNumber
    having count(*) > 4
) t1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4a49/23

Comment: would adding
`Group By status Having count(is_different_from_previous)>40`  right before "order by t1.time" satisfy the time requirement?

Comment: @simon just re-read your question, you'll have to add the `having count` clause right after `group by status`

Comment: @Simon maybe I misinterpreted the problem? I see 5 groups of 0s in your fiddle excluding the 0 at the beginning

Comment: that is true. i tried modifying your answer to include the time restriction. check the query again. i added the having count clause right after group by status

Answer (score 0):

Try the following modified query, which is more efficient than the earlier one, because another table scan is eliminated and we restrict the data to only the last one hour. Also, the first group is not counted.

**EDIT**: I changed the JOIN condition back to `st2.id = st1.id+1` to satisfy the requirements.

```
select 
  st1.status, 
  count(st1.id)
from sampletable st1
inner join sampletable st2
on (st2.id = st1.id+1 and st2.status <> st1.status)
where st1.status = 0 AND st1.time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 hour)
group by st1.status;
```

**Updated SQL Fiddle demo with same id, status data**:

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fad19/1)</kbd>

Comment: would you be able to add the time restriction and not counting first group restriction?

it's not that i want to exclude all first groups. i only want to exclude the first group IF it is ALSO the start of the table

Comment: Sure, let me give it a shot.

Comment: @Simon There you go! I have modified the query to not count the first group as well as restrict the data to only the last 1 hour (so, it will be much quicker).